# c++ Threadpool: should work be able to add more work to the work-queue

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want avoid the overhead of creating std::thread and therefore i'm going to implement a thread-pool. I'm struggling with one design-decision:

Should work in the work-queue be able to add work to the work-queue? If yes, how?

The problem arise, because i want to keep my work that i add to the work-queue as small as possible (but not smaller), to get a balanced work-flow. The problem is that if i allow work-items to add more work to the work-queue, that can easily leads to dead-locks, as far as i can see. And that looks like a deadlock to me.

My proposal to the dilemma is: Only add sub-work (work added by work) if one thread in the work-queue is idle.

Is this avoiding deadlocks? Is there a better way?

```
int sub_foo()
{
      return 10;
}

 void foo()
 {
        std::future<int> result = work_queue.add( sub_foo );
        std::cout << result.get();
 }


 int main()
 {
      std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;
      for( int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
           futures.push_back( work_queue.add( foo ));

      for( int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
      {
           futures.back().get();
           futures.pop_back();
      }
 }
```

ADD: Considering the case, that all threads in the work_queue are performing the foo function. They could not (as far as i see) and their work because they are waiting for result.get(), but this is still in the work_queue and cannot be performed, before one thread in the work_queue is free.

Comment: Deadlocks should only happen if work adds itself back onto the queue or work that will add work that will add work etc, etc.

Comment: Are you sure? The Work only leaves the work-queue, if it's done. But the sub-work has an higher work-queue index than the parent-work. Therefore the parent-work is waiting for the childwork and the childwork is waiting for the parent-work.

Comment: You should put up some example code, I've made thread-pools before and never had the issue you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the actual design, which you did not disclose in detail.

With simple message-queue (lockless or mutex) attached to each thread, and a round-robin message distributor, I see no dead-lock.